# Why argument has been changed when using subprocess(python) to start application(windows)?

Tags: python, debugging, parameters, parameter-passing

I use the python code below to start debugger and the application(a simple code I write myself) with argument:

```
debugger=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\windbg.exe'
exe='test.exe'
argument='\x01\x02...\xff'#from 0x01 to 0xff

subprocess.Popen(debugger+" "+exe+" "+argument)
```

Well it worked, but when I set a breakpoint in main function, and checked the argument, it seemed that argv[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK3gR.png)] is not exactly right:

[image]

It seems that '\x09' and '\x20' are changed to '\x00' and '\x22' is gone.

So what's wrong? Am I doing it in a wrong way?

Comment: show the whole code instead of `...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command with arguments shold be passed to `Popen` as list:

```
subprocess.Popen([debugger, exe, argument])
```